# customizing a UITabBar ios7-ios8 buttons and background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I've been stuggeling to change the uitabbar icons and background so it will look just the way I want it. everytime I change the background color it shows the color but not solid as the specific color I'm giving. also the images I set up for the items become gray when running.

so I have a CV for start with a start button.
button code:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [self storyboard];
Start *startViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"start"];
[self presentViewController:startViewController animated:NO completion:nil];}
```

as you can see it only send to the second VC which is the UITabBarController.
in the appdelegate i tried:

```
    Start *tabController = (Start *)self.window.rootViewController;

//tab1
UITabBar *tabBar = (UITabBar *)tabController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[item1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

//tab2
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
[item2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
//tab3
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
[item3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
//tab4
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
[item4 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

but it didn't seem to work. I look a lot but all I could find is tutorial about setFinishedSelectedImage: withFinishedUnselectedImage:; which didn't really help cause it's deprecated. all I could do so far is setting the uitabbar from the interfacebuilder.

to change the color I simply changed the tint and the background color. also tried putting a uiimageview behind the uitabbar but it didn't seems to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to costumizing a UITabBar ios7-ios8 use this code

```
 UITabBarItem *item0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

    item0.title = @"item0title";
    item1.title = @"item1title";
    item2.title=@"item2title";
    item3.title=@"item3title";


    [item0 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item0 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item2 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    [item3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item3 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    //[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[uicolor whitcolor]];
    //[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    //[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! sorry for the noobie question but where should i use it? im not sure how to refere from my appdelegate to the tabBar and i tried to create a UITabBarController without any success

Comment: create uitabarcontroller and in your storyboard select your tabarview and add your custom class